# Spring boot junit not working

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to add unit testing for my spring boot application. It doesn't work, and throws 404. I am using 1.2.1 release spring boot and have dependencies for spring-boot-starter-test. Please let know if i am missing something. The spring boot app works without any issue.

Here is my code,

```
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {//NOSONAR
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
       @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean displayListServletRegistrationBean(){
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new DisplayServlet(),"/display");
    }
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean manageServletRegistrationBean(){
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new ManageServlet(),"/manage");
    }

}
```

My junit test case code,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:application-test-context.xml"})
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=0", "management.port=0"})
@ActiveProfiles("scratch")

public class ApplicationTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testHome() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/display")).andExpect(status().isOk());
        //this.mvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

The console has

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/display] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
```

and Junit result has

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404> at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC Test is only designed for testing requests that are handled by Spring MVC's `DispatcherServlet`. It doesn't know anything about your `DisplayServlet` which is why, as shown in the log, the `DispatcherServlet` has tried to handle the request rather than your `DisplayServlet`.

There are a few different ways in which you could proceed. For example:

1. You could change your application to wrap your servlets using `ServletWrappingController` so that Spring MVC knows about them.
2. You could change your testing approach and use `RestTemplate` against a real server. You're actually already starting a real server by virtue of the `WebIntegrationTest` annotation on your test class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i unit test the spring boot main() method?

Comment: That's probably better tackled in a separate question